# How to add a custom set property as field on Mac version?

Tags: ms-word

`File > Properties > Custom`

[image]

I am then trying to insert the variable ('variable') as a field.

[image]

'variable' is not listed, nor do any = Formulas seem to work.

In previous windows versions, selecting DOCPROPERTY would allow a custom variable to be selected and inserted. But selecting DOCPROPERTY only causes an `Error! No property name supplied.`

I am trying to insert a custom field, which would be inserted in multiple places on the document, which could be updated in one place. Such as 'version 1.1'

Comment: Are you trying to do this with VBA code? If not, you have posted your question to the wrong forum. Use SuperUser or Microsoft Answers instead. If you are trying to do this with VBA code, then edit your question and include the code that you have tried so far and describe what is not working.

Comment: Here's where to post this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a custom field generated throw `File -> Properties... -> Custom` on Mac OS go to:

1. Insert tab
2. Insert a field
3. Choose `Document Information` category
4. Choose `DocProperty`
5. Click on `Options`
6. Choose your property and click on `Ok`
7. Click on `Ok`